# How to get the WorkitemCollection from WorkItemStore using Query(Ids, QueryString) Method

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have stuck on one problem where I want to get the `WorkItemCollection`  from the `WorkItemStore`. 
I know it can be possible by using [`Query()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore.query.aspx) Method.

But in my scenario `Query` method is not working as I am using method [`WorkItemStore.Query Method (Int32[], String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff732634.aspx).
with the `String` argument as

```
Select [System.Id],[System.State],[System.Title],[System.WorkItemType] 
from WORKITEMS 
where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Requirement' and [System.TeamProject] = 'Test_Baseline'
```

But while executing this query It is throwing exception with message as `Invalid Query Provided`.
Can any one tell how do I resolve this problem?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: That query works fine on my TFS, just by replacing the Team Project name in the query.

Comment: @DaveShaw yes, This query is running fine if I tried it on TFS directly.
But when I am using this query in the method `Query(Int32[], String)` it throws an exception. Ex. `WIStore.Query([1,2,3], QueryString)` in program.

Comment: I tried it with Query(string), I'm not sure why you are using that overload, it's not clear from the question, what you want to achieve, if it is just query for items with the ID put that in the where clause of the WIQL: ID in (1,2,3)

Comment: @DaveShaw yes, Dave I did it but the thing is I want to know why I am not able to use the `Query(int[], String)` as it has been documented by TFS team.
As, My Query is  fine, calling of function is correct..

Answer (score 3):

@Ankit,
The exception I got from running your query using Query(Int32[], String) oveload is:

*"The WHERE and ORDER BY clauses of a query string are not supported on a parameterized query."*

which I think explains why you cannot run this WIQL using this overload. You should either remove the WHERE clause from the query or use Query(String) method

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. however, I think the microsoft programmers are lazy fother muckers. The documentation does not say "oh and by the way you need to parse the g'damn query and remove all the conditions even though we aren't going to look at them."

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I am trying to implement a query function that will handle both LIST and TREE queries.  In the end I wrote something like this...

```
    JArray RunQuery(string wiql)
    {
        var i = wiql.ToLower().IndexOf("from workitemlinks");
        if (i > 0)
        {
            // Handle "Tree" queries
            var query = new Query(Store, wiql);
            var linkInfoList = query.RunLinkQuery();
            var parent = linkInfoList.ToDictionary(link => link.TargetId, link => link.SourceId);
            // Remove all WHERE and ORDER BY from query
            var items = tfs.Store.Query(parent.Keys.ToArray(), wiql.Substring(0, i) + "from workitems");
            var result = JsonUtil.ConvertItemList(items);
            foreach (JObject json in result)
            {
                json["Parent"] = parent[json.Value<int>("ID")];
            }
            return result;
        }
        // Handle "List" query
        return JsonUtil.ConvertItemList(Store.Query(wiql));
    }
```

I hope someone finds this helpful.